# best way to load custom made buttons in every subform of a form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms, class

I'm making a patient database in VS2019 in vb.net.
The main form with the patient overview has 8 custom made buttons.
I want those 8 buttons to load also in every subform i open from the mainform.

What would be the best way to approach this?
In the main panel i can click on the clients button.
It loads a form with those 8 buttons and a database list with clients.

If i open a client it opens in a new form and those 8 buttons should be loaded there as well.
Thanks for any advise on this matter. I'm a beginner.

edit: i added the code of the custombuttons class:
Imports FontAwesome.Sharp

Public Class CustomButtons
Sub createbutton(frm As Form)
Dim pnlTop As New Panel
Dim btnNew As New IconButton()
Dim btnDelete As New IconButton()
Dim btnEdit As New IconButton()
Dim btnSave As New IconButton()
Dim btnPrevious As New IconButton()
Dim btnNext As New IconButton()
Dim btnSearch As New IconButton()
Dim btnPrint As New IconButton()
Dim btnExport As New IconButton()
pnlTop.Location = New Point()

```
    btnNew.Location = New Point(0, 0)
    btnDelete.Location = New Point(0, 30)
    btnEdit.Location = New Point(0, 60)
    btnSave.Location = New Point(0, 90)
    btnPrevious.Location = New Point(0, 120)
    btnNext.Location = New Point(0, 150)
    btnSearch.Location = New Point(0, 180)
    btnPrint.Location = New Point(0, 210)
    btnExport.Location = New Point(0, 240)

    btnNew.IconChar = IconChar.Plus
    btnDelete.IconChar = IconChar.Minus
    btnEdit.IconChar = IconChar.Edit
    btnSave.IconChar = IconChar.Save
    btnPrevious.IconChar = IconChar.ChevronLeft
    btnNext.IconChar = IconChar.ChevronRight
    btnSearch.IconChar = IconChar.Search
    btnPrint.IconChar = IconChar.Print
    btnExport.IconChar = IconChar.FileExport

    btnNew.IconColor = Color.Green
    btnDelete.IconColor = Color.IndianRed
    btnEdit.IconColor = Color.Yellow
    btnSave.IconColor = Color.Orange
    btnPrevious.IconColor = Color.Aqua
    btnNext.IconColor = Color.Aqua
    btnSearch.IconColor = Color.LightSlateGray
    btnPrint.IconColor = Color.YellowGreen
    btnExport.IconColor = Color.White

    btnNew.IconSize = 60
    btnDelete.IconSize = 60
    btnEdit.IconSize = 60
    btnSave.IconSize = 60
    btnPrevious.IconSize = 60
    btnNext.IconSize = 60
    btnSearch.IconSize = 60
    btnPrint.IconSize = 60
    btnExport.IconSize = 60

    Dim buttons() As Button = {btnNew, btnDelete, btnEdit, btnSave, btnPrevious, btnNext, btnSearch, btnPrint, btnExport}
    For Each button As Button In buttons
        frm.Controls.Add(button)

    Next
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: [Add Controls to Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/dotnet/csharp/add-controls-to-windows-forms) should be good to start with

Comment: Maybe a custom control containing the buttons and code which can be added to each form https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/varieties-of-custom-controls?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: Probably not the best question for SO as "best practice" type questions can be quite subjective in it's current form and you would get a lot of varying replies.  Case in point, while both answers above are more than valid, you could always go down the track of a inherited form.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following steps to achieve it.
1.You could write a class to create buttons and register events for them.

```
  Public Class Create
   Sub createButton(frm As Form)

    Dim btn1 As New Button()
    Dim btn2 As New Button()
    Dim btn3 As New Button()
    Dim btn4 As New Button()
    Dim btn5 As New Button()
    btn1.Location = New Point(50, 90)
    btn2.Location = New Point(50, 130)
    btn3.Location = New Point(50, 170)
    btn4.Location = New Point(50, 210)
    btn5.Location = New Point(50, 250)
    btn1.Text = "button1"
    btn2.Text = "button2"
    btn3.Text = "button3"
    btn4.Text = "button4"
    btn5.Text = "button5"
    AddHandler btn1.Click, AddressOf btn1_Click
    AddHandler btn2.Click, AddressOf btn2_Click
    Dim buttons() As Button = {btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5}
    For Each button As Button In buttons
        frm.Controls.Add(button)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub btn1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim form2 As New Form2
    form2.Show()
End Sub
Private Sub btn2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim form3 As New Form3
    form3.Show()
End Sub
......
End Class
```

2.In the Load event of each form, you can call the method in the class.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim cl As New Create
    cl.createButton(Me)
End Sub
End Class
```

......

```
Public Class Form3
Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim cl As New Create
    cl.createButton(Me)
End Sub
End Class
```

[image]

Result:
[image]

Comment: I tried to implement your answer but couldn't get the class to work into the form,

Comment: You need to manually create several forms first, and then implement this class in the Load event of the form. If you have already done it, you could debug with a breakpoint to see where the problem is.